# How do I make a HTML background image extend its width outside of the parent DIV

Tags: html, css, position, repeat

I have a header image which I want to be positioned horizontally, stretched across the top of a website. The width needs to be the same as the browser window.

This is exactly the same as the dark bar at the top of StackOverflow.

My wrapper DIV has a fixed width therefore my image is appearing only for the width of the DIV. How can I make it the full width of the browser window?

Comment: Move it outside the wrapper div?

Comment: You can not make an element’s background appear outside of the element’s dimensions. _“My wrapper DIV has a fixed width therefore my image is appearing only for the width of the DIV. How can I make it the full width of the browser window?”_ – by making it the background of a different element, that is not width-restricted in that way … (for example `body` or `html` could come to mind)

Comment: wow, okay, yeah that's what I was gonna say.. I have water in a cup, i want it to expand beyond the boundaries of the cup... pour it out of tha cup;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. Background images will always be contained within it's parent element. What you could try doing is instead of using the image as a background on your parent element, you could drop it into it's own element and bring that element outside of the container.

For instance:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="headerImage">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li><a href="">Link One</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="otherContent"></div>
</div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
.container {
    position: static; // This allows the image to break outside of it's container.
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.headerImage {
    background: url(yourImage.png) center top no-repeat transparent;
    display: block;
    position: absolute; // This breaks it out of the normal document flow.
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; // This will expand to fill the width of the window.
    height: 65px; // Or whatever height you want.
    z-index: 10; // Play with this number for layering.
}
```

Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just take out your header div from the wrapper div and then apply css of image background to the div and you will get the desired output.
Just try below code by separating header out of your wrapper div.

```
.header{
  background-image:url('http://s8.postimg.org/8gehir3e9/Screen_Shot_2014_05_30_at_9_03_30_AM.png');
  background-repeat:repeat-x; 
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make a parent div to your div that have a width of 100%